# Solving an equation including $\ln$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $$8x^2+2\ln x-6=0$$

How should I approach this? Should I do $8x^2=e^{\ln{x^2}}$?

Comment: Lambert W function.  That's the best you can do.  Or numerical methods.

Answer (score 1):

The real solution:

$$8x^2+2\ln(x)-6=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$8x^2+2\ln(x)=6\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$2\left(4x^2+\ln(x)\right)=6\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$4x^2+\ln(x)=3\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$e^{4x^2+\ln(x)}=e^{3}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$e^{4x^2}\cdot e^{\ln(x)}=e^{3}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$e^{4x^2}\cdot x=e^{3}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$xe^{4x^2}=e^{3}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x=\frac{e^{3}}{e^{4x^2}}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x=e^{3-4x^2}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x^2=\left(e^{3-4x^2}\right)^2\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x^2=e^{6-8x^2}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x=\sqrt{\frac{\text{W}\left(8e^6\right)}{4}}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\text{W}\left(8e^6\right)}{2}}$$

With $\text{W}(z)$ is te product log function

Comment: You could note $W_k(z)$ to find all solutions.

Answer (score -2):

The best method to solve these types of transcendental equations is with graphs.

Comment: How is this quadratic in $e^t$?

Comment: My mistake, $t$ will not be constant. Deleted the word "quadritic".

Comment: Moreover this is **not** a polynomial equation. Just try to solve it and you will see.

Comment: Changed my answer. Hope this satisfies some criteria.